# opcua python library call_method correct use

Tags: python, opc-ua

i need to write python code to retrieve a file from an opcua server calling the method ReadProgram available on the server. The method has input and output arguments ([method attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stzXV.jpg), [input attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjnv.jpg), [output attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEShb.jpg), [successful call with ua expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IwkL.jpg)).

I wrote the following code to retrieve the program:

```
from opcua import Client, ua
client = Client("opc.tcp://10.254.92.26:4880", timeout=5000)
client.connect()

method = client.get_node("ns=2; i=399800")
input = method.get_child(["0:InputArguments"])

input_arg = ua.Variant([0], ua.VariantType.UInt16)
result = method.call_method(input, input_arg)

client.disconnect()
```

But i get the following error on row 9 (result = ....): "The method id does not refer to a method for the specified object."(BadMethodInvalid).

I'm absolutely new to opcua. I have already read many posts about this subject, but in no one the right way to work is completely described. Someone can help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A method needs to be called via the parent object.

```
obj = client.get_node("ns=2; i=?")
input_arg = ua.Variant([0], ua.VariantType.UInt16)
result = method.call_method("2:ReadProgramm", input_arg)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but is not so clear for me. I put:  obj=client.get_node("ns=2; i=399860") --> parent of ReadProgram
method=obj.get_child("2:ReadProgram"), but result is the same. Anyway thank you very much

Comment: Doest method = obj.get_child("2:ReadProgramm") work? Maybe you have the wrong namespace index of the qualified name for the method.

Comment: I have not an error on obj.get_child("2:ReadProgram"),  but also in this way i get the same error on result = method.call_method("2:ReadProgramm", input_arg)

Answer (score 0):

This code work well:

```
from opcua import Client, ua
client = Client("opc.tcp://10.254.92.26:4880")
client.connect()

obj=client.get_node("ns=2; i=399860") #this is the parent of the method
method=obj.get_child("2:ReadProgram")
input_arg = ua.Variant([0], ua.VariantType.UInt16)

result = obj.call_method(method, input_arg)

client.disconnect()
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This may help :```method_0 = client1.get_node("ns=***;s=*****")
    parent_obj_0 = "ns=*;s=***"
    obj_1 = client1.get_node(parent_obj_0)
    out_1 = obj_0.call_method(method_0)```